# Evaluate the possibility of getting a zero Exclusive Or value of N numbers, each of which may range from 0 to M inclusive

Tags: probability

Evaluate the possibility of getting a zero Exclusive Or value of N numbers, each of which ranges from 0 to M inclusive. 
For example, when N=3, M=2, there are a total of 27 cases, 6 of which can produce a XOR value of 0, hence the possibility is 2/9.
However, I am not able to work out the general formula for the possibilities. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: What does XOR in this case mean?  It's TRUE if all of the $N$ numbers are different from one another?

Comment: Or is that an odd number of the $N$ numbers have a non-zero value?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  I presume you are looking at the bitwise XOR.  It is easy if $M$ is one less than a power of $2$.  Then you can just pick the first $N-1$ to be anything and the last has to be the XOR of the rest, so the chance is $\frac 1{M+1}$  Otherwise, the next to last has to bring the XOR into the range $[0,M]$ so the last can neutralize it.  If $M$ is close to the next power of $2$ you will be close (but not exact) to take the XOR of the first $N-2$ to be equally distributed, then the chance that the next to last brings it into range, then the chance that the last brings you to zero.  If $M$ is just above a power of $2$ it gets more complicated because it can take several tries to get the last into range.