# What does it mean to take the exclusive OR of the three numbers $0, 2, 1$?

Tags: logic

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642241/evaluate-the-possibility-of-getting-a-zero-exclusive-or-value-of-n-numbers-each) asks about the exclusive-OR'ing of several numbers, each of which can assume more than two values (that is, more than $0$ and $1$).

What does this mean?  I did a Google search and found information on the ternary exclusive-OR, but that still involves $true$ and $false$ values, not $0, 1, 2, 3, ...$

Any ideas?

Comment: As long as they're all natural numbers, it probably means to interpret them in binary and XOR their bits. But it may be best to wait for the original poster to clarify. (It's been, what, less than half an hour since you posted a comment there? Have some patience, eh?) By the way, since the XOR operation is associative, it easily generalizes to more than two inputs: $x\oplus y\oplus z=x\oplus(y\oplus z)=(x\oplus y)\oplus z$.

Comment: Well, the question did get an upvote, which indicates that the question probably isn't nonsense.  That, and after thinking about it a bit, it seemed a decent question to ask in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking them bitwise, which is probably what is intended, you have $00 \oplus 10 \oplus 01=11$

Answer (score -2):

Exclusive-OR, or XOR in short, is an operation which will return true if an odd number of its inputs is true. It iwll return false if an even number of its inputs is false.

For example, an input of TTFTFFT will give false since there are 4 T's.

an input of TTTFFFFFFFF will be true since there are 3 T's.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: That does make sense, but in the context of the question I linked to, the values can be more than just $T$ and $F$ if I'm reading that question correctly.  What of that?  Or is there no context in which that makes sense?

Comment: It may be a bitwise XOR. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/XOR.html